# getting key-value pairs of custom object in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working with the [python boto package called mws](http://boto.cloudhackaers.com/en/latest/ref/mws.html#) for interfacing with Amazon MWS.  But I think this is also a general python question, still not sure. I am using the `list_oder_items` method to get the product items for an order.

```
items = conn.list_order_items(AmazonOrderId = order_id)
result = items.ListOrderItemsResult
```

Then I will want to save each item.

```
for item in result.OrderItems.OrderItem:
    save_item_to_db(item)
```

Here the `item` variable is a type `<class 'boto.mws.response.OrderItem'>`, which if you print it out shows this:

> OrderItem{}(Title: u'title',
>   GiftWrapPrice: USD 0.00, ConditionNote: u'Brand New& Authentic
>   product....', CODFee: None, ASIN: u'XXXX', OrderItemId:
>   u'XXXX', CODFeeDiscount: None, QuantityShipped: u'1',
>   GiftWrapTax: USD 0.00, ShippingPrice: USD 3.99, QuantityOrdered: u'1',
>   ItemTax: USD 0.00, PromotionIds: [], SellerSKU:
>   u'XXXX', ShippingDiscount: USD 0.00, ShippingTax: USD
>   0.00, ConditionId: u'New', PromotionDiscount: USD 0.00, ItemPrice: USD 12.81, ConditionSubtypeId: u'New')

why can't I iterate over the key-value pairs like `for key in item: print key`?  Just a silly though I also tried this: `for key in dict(item): print key`.  That didn't print anything either.

I would just like to have a more systematic approach for dealing with the `item` object than visual inspection.  Is it possible to turn it into a normal python dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are getting an object and you want to iterate over all the fields of that object as key:value pair.

You can try object.`_dict_` to get dictionary representation of the object.

code example:

```
for key in item.__dict__:
    print key
```